# How to add a PDF attachment to an Outlook email suing VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to figure out how to attach a PDF document to an Outlook email using VBA. This is a project for the Customer Service Representatives at the company I work for.

They receive this PDF into their Outlook inbox. Is there a way I can reference the title of this email (perhaps in a cell) so that the PDF attachment is added to the email my program is sending out? Or forwarded along with the email?

```
Sub RFAEmail()

    'Current Code:

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Dim strbody1 As String
    Dim strbody2 As String
    Dim strbody3 As String
    Dim strbody4 As String
    Dim strbody5 As String
    Dim strbody6 As String
    Dim strbody7 As String
    Dim strbody8 As String
   
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    strbody1 = "" & Space(1) & Range("B5")
    strbody2 = "Customer:" & Space(1) & Range("C5")
    strbody3 = "" & Space(1) & Range("D5")
    strbody4 = "Current:" & Space(1) & Range("E5")
    strbody5 = "Proposed:" & Space(1) & Range("F5")
    strbody6 = "Changes:" & Space(1) & Range("H5")
    strbody7 = "Other Notes:" & Space(1) & Range("I5")
    strbody8 = "PDF" & Space(1) & Range("G5")
    
    strbody = strbody1 & vbNewLine & strbody2 & vbNewLine & strbody3 & vbNewLine & strbody4 & vbNewLine & strbody5 & vbNewLine & strbody6 & vbNewLine & strbody7 & vbNewLine & strbody8
 

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "JOB CHANGE" & Space(1) & Range("B5")
        .Body = strbody
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Request Sent", vbApplicationModal, "Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: post your current code

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the attached file on the disk to be able to send it out later. The [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Attachment.SaveAsFile) method saves the attachment to the specified path. For example:

```
Sub SaveAttachment()  
 Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector  
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem  
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 

 Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector  
 If Not TypeName(myInspector) = "Nothing" Then  
   If TypeName(myInspector.CurrentItem) = "MailItem" Then  
     Set myItem = myInspector.CurrentItem  
     Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments  
     'Prompt the user for confirmation  
     Dim strPrompt As String  
     strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the first attachment in the current item to the Documents folder? If a file with the same name already exists in the destination folder, it will be overwritten with this copy of the file."  
     If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then  
       myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & _  
       myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName  
     End If  
   Else  
     MsgBox "The item is of the wrong type."  
   End If  
 End If  
End Sub
```

The [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method creates a new attachment in the Attachments collection. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

```
Sub AddAttachment() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 

 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
 myAttachments.Add "C:\Test.doc", _ 
 olByValue, 1, "Test" 
 myItem.Display 
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there anyway I could copy & paste the email title containing the PDF in say Range("A1") and have VBA attach the PDF from that Email to mine? Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Nope. But you can paste the file path to the excel range. So, then you can attach the file by using the range value.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Is there a better way this could be done? I am trying to minimize the amount of steps they take when sending out this email.

Comment: Nope. You must save the email first. Only then you can attach the saved file as an attachment.

Comment: Would something like myAttachments.Add "C:\Downloads" & Range("A1") work? I apologize if I am being a nuisance.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks so much for the help!